# How to `conda install` on a server with no internet connection?

Tags: conda

I tried to run `tensorflow_gpu` on a server with no internet connection.

The script that runs `tensorflow_gpu` failed with this error:

`Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load libmkl_avx2.so or libmkl_def.so.`

I found a solution to this problem in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659453/intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-libmkl-avx2-so-or-libmkl-def-so), I have to do the following:

```
conda install nomkl numpy scipy scikit-learn numexpr
conda remove mkl mkl-service
```

Since the server has no internet connection, I have completely no idea of how I can install those packages.

What packages do I need to upload to the server in order to mimic `conda install`?

Comment: Do you have Conda installed already? It's not clear from the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been answered before at Stack Overflow: 
[Install anaconda library from a local source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316951/install-anaconda-library-from-a-local-source)

I am copying and rephrasing from the best answer there.

**(1) Download the tar files for the desired packages.**

Search for packages using a computer that DOES have an internet connection.  Copy it over to the server that does NOT have an internet connection.  Remember the path.

Example package:
https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/pymc-2.3.5-np110py35_0.tar.bz2

**(2) Then run conda install in offline mode, with server path to tar files.**

```
conda install --offline $home/savedfile/pymc-2.3.5-np110py35_0.tar.bz2  
# Substitute with your path and directory syntax based on your OS.
```

This question is old so you may have already found a solution.  If not, here it is.